# Why does openness on X imply openness on Y?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered the following problem today, which I am not able to solve (is it true?)
Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of
locally noetherian schemes. Let P be a property of f that is open on X. Under what conditions will it then hold true that the condition P is open on Y, and why?

Comment: What does it mean for P to be open on X or Y?

Comment: That if x is a point where the property holds, there is an open nbhs where P holds.